# What is the SRID of LCC projection?

Tags: postgis, raster, coordinate-system, proj

I have a raster file with LCC projection  and a point dataset with SRID 4326. I want to extract raster value to point. When I use the query

```sql
SELECT ST_Value(rast, geom) val
FROM testraster5, pft_account
WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, geom)
```

I'm not getting any result. However the point lies on the raster. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the intersection within the same CRS, so you have to reproject one layer to the other.

In QGIS, you have to use `Raster -> Projections -> Warp` to convert the raster to WGS84. You might need to remove the LCC layer and turn OTF **OFF** to see them align. Check that QGIS has assigned the right CRS to the reprojected layer when loading.

`Save As ...` is only useful to reproject vector data.

Answer (score 1):

If your data are in different CRS you have to reproject one of them.

```sql
SELECT ST_Value(rast, geom) val
FROM testraster5, pft_account
WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, ST_Transform(geom, EPSG_YOUR_RASTER));
```

Comment: The projection information of my raster is PROJCS["Lambert Conformal Conic",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9108"]],

Comment: AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",35.17280444444446],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",12.472955],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",24],PARAMETER["central_meridian",80],PARAMETER["false_easting",4000000],PARAMETER["false_northing",4000000],UNIT["meters",1]]

Comment: And the point data has EPSG:4326. When I add these two dataset on qgis, the point data sits on raster. If I reproject any one of them then they dont sit on each other.

Comment: EPSG:3034 is not the right code for the given LCC parameters. You have to use a custom CRS for it.

Comment: @Aparna: QGIS reproject PostGIS or other data automatically, In PostGIS you have to do manually with ST_Transform. If the EPSG code is different then use that.

Comment: The automatic reprojection (OTF) in QGIS is only for rendering, any intersection done inside QGIS needs layers of the same CRS as well.